# Cache RxJava reactive value with TTL

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Does RxJava have something similar to [Project Reactor's](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-)

```
Mono.cache(
    Function<? super T, Duration> ttlForValue,
    Function<Throwable, Duration> ttlForError,
    Supplier<Duration> ttlForEmpty
)
```

?

The use-case is to get a token with TTL once and cache it for subsequent subscribers until it expires. Token's TTL is part of the token structure and the `ttlForValue` function helps to retrieve it.

Comment: No and I'm not aware of any 3rd party library with such operator.